# Cloudfront 502 when using an ALB as custom origin via Lambda@Edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudfront

I filter requests to have crawlers and bots consuming a dedicated origin.
This origin is an express webserver using puppeteer on ECS, behind an ALB.

Calling directly the ALB using public DNS name works  - the required content is served as expected.

I use two Lambda@Edge functions to filter the incoming requests:

- first one at viewer request to "tag" the request by adding a header,
- second one at origin request to change the origin of the request, from S3 to custom origin (the ALB).

Everything works fine, the lambda are triggered, but the result is a 502 from cloudfront:

```
<H1>502 ERROR</H1>
    <H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
    <HR noshade size="1px">
    CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.
    We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
    configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
```

The origin is changed as in the examples:

```
   request.origin = {
    custom: {
     domainName: 'XXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com',
     port: 3000,
     protocol: 'https',
     path: '',
     sslProtocols: ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"],
     readTimeout: 5,
     keepaliveTimeout: 5,
     customHeaders: {}
    }
   };
   request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: 'XXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com' }];
```

As said previously, calling `XXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com:3000` directly using Postman works perfectly fine.

I checked the protocol, added the custom origin in the "Origins" of Cloudfront without change of the result...I am running out of ideas !

Am I missing something ?!
Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `https` with `XXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com` domain, as this domain belongs to AWS. You have to have **your own** domain for the ALB if you want to use `https` for it.

You can only use `http` connection with `XXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com` domains.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for your answers.
I can reach ```https://XXX.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com```using postman directly or my browser ; but I think you show something. The certificates does not include this name as alternate, I am trying to put everything back in http behind the Cloudfront to see if this changes things. But I am not sure that this will solve, as I was using http previously ; I introduced https...to solve this error in the first place ;)

Comment: @Ezechiel You can't use https with aws default domain. For cloudfront you must have valid SSL certificate for your own domain.

Comment: I do have a valid certificate for my own domain ; actually the ALB is already used with https for other internal endpoints, using this certificate.
I have removed SSL for this particuliar listener but still get a 502, I am trying to figure out where - between the behaviors and such - this occurs...